# Is Adobe Flash only for browsers?

Tags: flash

My general question is, can SOFTWARE also be dependent on Adobe Flash or is this something that is only for Internet browsers?

I'll explain my personal issue so you understand why I'm asking.
I'm trying to use a software called "EseeCloud" to view and download footage from my Jennov NVR security cameras. I am able to connect to the cameras but can't view or download them, getting an error "Could not load plugin." (see screenshot). The company support team answered as follows:

*"About the plugin ,normally, it's your computer question, not our software problems.
Because you and our computer use security software different,so I can't give you a clear answer.
But your can google search this question,you need change your computer setting to load plugin."*

Searching Google for this "plugin" warning, all I get are answers to how to change Chrome, Firefox, etc.. settings to enable flash. Nothing about actual software.

So I wanted to know if on Windows 7, there is some security setting or service that would be preventing me from using this software and if you think it has anything to do with Adobe Flash.

[image]

Comment: this isnt google :c

Comment: You can use that answer for EVERY question posted on this form.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still a bit vague.
Generally Flash is designed to run in a browser. So it belongs to the security measures of the browser.

Beside that, with Flexbuilder from Adobe you are able to run Flash as a pseudo program.

From that what I understand from your post, is that the security settings from your browser (Flash) blocks the feature you want. In Flash you have a variety of settings you could try.

This maybe a not sufficient answer for you but perhaps it gives you a direction.

**EDIT because of comment**
To be a bit more clear. A Software can use Flash and it can somehow depend on Flash, but IMHO this is something to avoid (personal flavor).
If so, your Software is mixing two different software types for different purposes.
So, at the end, it comes out the same as the support means.
If your software uses special plugins wich maybe mixed up with Flash, it is mostly a security setting on your computer/Flash/software to allow Software <-> Flash

Comment: Just to clarify what you wrote "...is that the security settings from your browser"... no, I'm not using a browser. This is a program (software) that I installed and run on Windows 7 like you would any other program. No browsers are used.

Comment: Then it seems to be a Flexapp? If so, there are security settings between Flash and the OS, as well.
Because otherwise, I don't understand what it could have to do with Flash.

Comment: I debugged the exe and some of the javascript of the software and see things like "--register-pepper-plugin"... but nothing about flexapp. When Googling "register-pepper-plugin" I also get lots of Adobe Flash Chrome results... so can it be that it actually DOES use some form of Flash?

Comment: Ok, now I see lots about flash.         flashPluginActivated: function() {
            Ext.data.flash.BinaryXhr.flashPluginActive = true;
            Ext.data.flash.BinaryXhr.flashPlugin = document.getElementById("ext-flash-polyfill");
            Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent("flashready");
        },
        // let a

I will investigate further and see what a software has to do with flash and how I can make sure that flash is not being blocked by it on my PC.

Comment: Seems that your software uses Chrome WebKit with Flash plugin maybe. In that case it comes back to My answer with (security) settings for external software parts.